# Building object file with `swiftc -emit-object` also emitting `_main` implementation

Tags: swift, compilation

I'm currently building object files using `swiftc`, with:

```
swiftc -emit-object bar.swift
```

where `bar.swift` is something simple like:

```
class Bar {
  var value: Int

  init(value: Int) {
    self.value = value
  }

  func plusValue(_ value: Int) -> Int {
    return self.value + value
  }
}
```

When I then move on to linking this against my main object to create an executable, I get the following error:

```
$ cc -o foobar foo.o bar.o
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    foo.o
    bar.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This indicates that `swiftc` is adding a `main` implementation to the object file, which can be confirmed with:

```
$ nm bar.o | grep _main
0000000000000000 T _main
```

As far as I can tell, this added function does very little:

```
$ otool -tV bar.o
bar.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000000000000    pushq   %rbp
0000000000000001    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000000000004    xorl    %eax, %eax
0000000000000006    movl    %edi, -0x4(%rbp)
0000000000000009    movq    %rsi, -0x10(%rbp)
000000000000000d    popq    %rbp
000000000000000e    retq
000000000000000f    nop
....snip...
```

Is there a way to tell `swiftc -emit-object` to not add this vestigial implementation of `main`?

Comment: From the information in https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/Driver.md I would *guess* that you need to pass the `-emit-library` option to the Swift compiler.

Comment: @MartinR this does create an artefact that works, but it's a `dylib`, and my preference was to have a statically linked executable at the end of this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short answer

The command line argument that I was missing was:

```
-parse-as-library
```

#### Long answer

In my quest to find an answer, I resorted to looking at the Swift source code on Github, and with a bit of luck found the following [compiler invocation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/validation-test/stdlib/CommandLine.swift#L4) in the test suite:

```
// RUN: %target-build-swift %S/Inputs/CommandLineStressTest/CommandLineStressTest.swift -parse-as-library -force-single-frontend-invocation -module-name CommandLineStressTestSwift -emit-object -o %t/CommandLineStressTestSwift.o
```

According to `swiftc --help`, `-parse-as-library` causes the compiler to:

> Parse the input file(s) as libraries, not scripts

This has proven to work for me, and the only difference in exported symbols is the removal of `_main`:

```
$ diff -U1 <(swiftc -emit-object -module-name bar -o a.o bar.swift && nm a.o | cut -c18-) <(swiftc -emit-object -parse-as-library -module-name bar -o b.o bar.swift && nm b.o | cut -c18-)
--- /dev/fd/63  2020-03-28 17:13:08.000000000 +1100
+++ /dev/fd/62  2020-03-28 17:13:08.000000000 +1100
@@ -23,3 +23,2 @@
 U __objc_empty_cache
-T _main
 s _objc_classes
```

and in the generated assembly the only change is the removal of the `_main` code:

```
$ diff -U1 <(swiftc -emit-object -module-name bar -o a.o bar.swift && objdump -d -no-leading-addr -no-show-raw-insn a.o) <(swiftc -emit-object -parse-as-library -module-name bar -o b.o bar.swift && objdump -d -no-leading-addr -no-show-raw-insn b.o)
--- /dev/fd/63  2020-03-28 17:19:03.000000000 +1100
+++ /dev/fd/62  2020-03-28 17:19:03.000000000 +1100
@@ -1,15 +1,5 @@

-a.o:   file format Mach-O 64-bit x86-64
+b.o:   file format Mach-O 64-bit x86-64

 Disassembly of section __TEXT,__text:
-_main:
-   pushq   %rbp
-   movq    %rsp, %rbp
-   xorl    %eax, %eax
-   movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
-   movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
-   popq    %rbp
-   retq
-   nop
-
 _$S3bar3BarC5valueSivg:
```