# how can I link swift object files with ld or clang?

Tags: swift, frameworks, clang, ld

I have two swift files. main.swift and other.swift.
I compile them as such

```
swiftc -emit-object main.swift other.swift Greeter
```

When I do:

```
clang -o Greet main.o other.o
```

I get:

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swift_Concurrency'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftXPC'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftIOKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftSwiftOnoneSupport'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Swift.String.init(stringInterpolation: Swift.DefaultStringInterpolation) -> Swift.String", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "Swift.String.init(_builtinStringLiteral: Builtin.RawPointer, utf8CodeUnitCount: Builtin.Word, isASCII: Builtin.Int1) -> Swift.String", referenced from:

<removed some messages for brevity>
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

Can you tell what's wrong?

I tried using `ld` instead and pass a directory to its search path, but it didn't seem to make a difference. I did the following:

```
ld main.o Other.o -syslibroot -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode13.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx \
-syslibroot -L/usr/lib/swift -syslibroot -L/Applications/Xcode13.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -o Greet
```

Comment: Huh that's weird. I wonder why [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60889010/5133585) was able to do it.

Comment: For other users getting here from Google: I was getting this error, but found that your `-L/usr/lib/swift` was sufficient to fix it for me.